# как интегрировать клиентскую часть (Gulp.js) в мавен проект

Tags: maven

У меня такая структура проекта:

Maven project
 - Client (Gulp.js)
 - Server(maven - spring-boot)
Сначала я запускаю сервер, потом отдельно клиента.
Pom.xml файл находится в сервере. Как можно и интегрировать клиентскую часть в серверную, что б в будущем я смог задеплоить проект на сервере? Спасибо